# Chaining ajax calls using then, handling expected failure

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

I have a call thus:

```
$.ajax({url:"url", ....}).then(function(response) {
  if (response.sucess) {
    return $.ajax({.....});
  }
  else {
    //what do I return here so the next then doesn't fire but no error is raised?
  }
}).then(function(response2) {
   //....Do more stuff
});
```

So the first `ajax` call returns a success flag. If this succeeds then I want it to continue. If it doesn't I want to prevent the next `then` from firing. I'm unsure what I should return from the first then when `success == false`?

I feel like I should return a `$.Deferred` as this is what `then` expects but I'm not sure how to do this being as I'm not firing another `deferred` action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Need to return a [.reject();](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.reject/)

```
$.ajax({url:"url", ....}).then(function(response) {
  if (response.sucess) {
    return $.ajax({.....});
  }
  else {
    return $.Deferred().reject();
  }
}).then(function(response2) {
   //....Do more stuff
});
```

Comment: It's somewhat academic but by rights it should be `return $.Deferred().reject().promise();`.

Comment: To put it on a par with `return $.ajax(...)`. In general, Deferreds are kept private to the function where they are created and only the derived promise is revealed to the calling function. The reason why I say it is academic in this case is because your Deferred is returned in a rejected state, so it can't be interfered with.